# Enable SSL "Mutual Authentication" for WebServices and "One Way Authentication" for the GUI?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, tomcat6

I need to apply SSL "Mutual Authentication" for Web services (SOAP) and the "One Way Authentication" for Web pages to avoid having certificates in the browser. For informationg, the GUI and SOAP Webservices are in the same war module.

I used SSL Mutual authentication at the Tomcat container level:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" 
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="true"
sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="D:\certificates\demo-keystore"
keystorePass="xxxxxxxx"
truststoreFile="D:\certificates\demo-truststore"
truststorePass="xxxxxxxx"/>
```

- clientAuth="true" imply that a valid certificate chain should be provided by the client (from both a browser and a web service consumer) before accepting a connection. I know that it is possible to configure the SSL connector to not require a certificate chain from the client by using clientAuth="false" and then applying WS-Security at the message level by using WSS4J interceptors but i want to know if there is another solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL%20Support) about clientAuth attribute:

> Set to true if you want the SSL stack to require a valid certificate
>   chain from the client before accepting a connection. Set to want if
>   you want the SSL stack to request a client Certificate, but not fail
>   if one isn't presented. A false value (which is the default) will not
>   require a certificate chain unless the client requests a resource
>   protected by a security constraint that uses CLIENT-CERT
>   authentication.

I set the clientAuth to "false" and configured CLIENT-CERT authentication in the WEB-INF/web.xml. This will require a client certificate for Web services with url pattern /ws/*:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>CXFServlet</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [APR connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) which has different attributes for many SSL settings and configure `SSLVerifyClient`

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt" 
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
       SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
```

The [available options](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL%20Support) for  `SSLVerifyClient` are

> Ask client for certificate. The default is "none", meaning the client will not have the opportunity to submit a certificate. Other acceptable values include "optional", "require" and "optionalNoCA".

If you configure it as optional, then the GUI could not present the certificate (because are not mandatory). To ensure that the client certificate has been presented with WebServices, check for the existence of `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` in `HttpServletRequest`